# What is the priority on NoStepInto entries in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I've been looking into the NoStepInto feature of Visual Studio. 
Andy Pennell's post [How to Not Step Into Functions using the Visual C++ Debugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/andypennell/archive/2004/02/06/69004.aspx) has been extremely helpful.

But as far as I can tell, in VS2008 the string name of the rule no longer has to be an integer, and no longer has any effect on the priority of the rule.

I have played around with the registry a bit and it seems to use the best match or maximal match (not sure what the correct expression is).

So if I have the following two rules

```
boost              boost\:\:.*=NoStepInto
boost::shared_ptr  boost\:\:shared_ptr.*=StepInto
```

it does step into shared pointers, which I assume is because the second rule is a more exact match.

Has anyone come across any information on anywhere confirming or refuting this? I can't seem to find any.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and things seem to work the way I expect them to:

```
20    boost\:\:.*=NoStepInto
30    boost\:\:shared_ptr.*=StepInto
```

Does not step me into any `boost` namespace functions, except for `shared_ptr`'s.

Changing the priorities around to

```
10    boost\:\:shared_ptr.*=StepInto
20    boost\:\:.*=NoStepInto
```

Does not step me into any `boost` namespace functions at all.

Comment: Well, it's possible that it's a bug in VS2008 that they fixed in the first service pack.